# Scrolling Toolbar stops working if the CoordinatorLayout parent has non-zero vertical padding

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

No idea why this happens but a plain Toolbar (or MaterialToolbar) will refuse to scroll if the parent CoordinatorLayout has non-zero padding.

Example xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="1dp">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?backgroundColor"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/more_actions"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_more_horiz_24"
        />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I can confirm that wrapping the `CoordinatorLayout` in a `FrameLayout` and applying the padding to that instead fixes the issue. I would however prefer to avoid this.